# Twitter Bootstrap parsing warnings with RoR 3.2.2 / Firefox 12.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've added Twitter Boostrap support to our RoR 3.2.2 app via Twitter-Bootstrap-Rails gem.  It seems to work fine, but when browsing our app using FireFox 12.0 on some (not all) of our OSX Lion dev boxes, we're getting *loads* (more than FF log can hold) of warnings like the following when the app pages load:

```
Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped.


filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endC...

bootst...?body=1 (line 3081, col 17)
```

which refers to

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endColorstr='#bd362f', GradientType=0);
```

in assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.

These warnings do not occur with Chrome nor Safari on OSX, nor do they occur with IE9 nor FireFox 7.01 or FireFox 12 on Windows 7.  So it appears to be an issue with FireFox 12 on OSX but I can't tell for sure.  FF appears to be trying to load IE-specific style attributes here.

Thanks in adv for any input - Michael

Comment: I'm guessing your CSS passes validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd always put or import IE-specific styles inside a conditonal comment;
 for these type of errors.

This is why we have "This site best works under Chrome" or FF or IE etc banners on websites. :-)

Comment: Thx, but don't think that is it.

The warnings appear only on some macs, and only with FF12. I'm thinking there is some environment difference on some of our machines where a precompile step is happening and others where it is not...

Comment: From Mark Dotto, one of the bootstrap devs. "Everyone get's the filter attribute, but not everyone processes it (only IE should). If you're using LESS, might be a parsing error instead (so make sure filter is escaped). Otherwise, I don't see any errors on our end. Please open another issue if you have any more details to share."

Comment: Thanks TheIrishGuy -- a LESS parsing error seems very probably here.  As we're moving offices I cannot verify today but it is the first thing I'll try.  Also, since it works fine on other macs with same browser etc. a difference in preparsing / environment is almost certainly the case.